# Download / Open PDF with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, download

I am facing the problem that I want to have two buttons, you can open or download a PDF on a server like:

```
<button id="download">download pdf</button>
<button id="open">open pdf</button>
```

But I don't have any idea how to achieve this. I already found that:

```
<a href="x.pdf" download="x.pdf">PDF Download</a>
```

BUT: HTML5 download attribute is not working in all browsers and it needs to be cross browser save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` attribute with `window.open("x.pdf");` or you move it into a own function.

Comment: That just opens the pdf, but what to do with the download option?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

JavaScript file which allows for cross-browser download support

Comment: Please provide the code sample inside the answer. Link might be broken one day

Comment: Thanks for that link! But I didn't find a way to save files that already exists on the server. In my case the file I want to save is not generated, it already exists on my server